# When switching from Apache to Fast CGI, pages of the site are being downloaded instead of displayed in browser

Tags: php, fastcgi

I run a site and blog on the same server, blog is located in the /blog/ directory in the root folder and it is a simple wordpress blog.

The problem, I have had to run an update on the blog which is constantly failing. After talking to my hosting provider, I have discovered that I am apparently running php as Apache and not as fast cgi, which is a main reason why I was not able to run all updates on my blog. We have changed it to fast cgi in plesk panel and blog started to work and run all necessary updates as it was supposed to do, but the main site began malfunctioning, basically instead of displaying page in the browser, all pages were firing up a download dialogue.

I have had to change everything back to where I have started, but need to get to the bottom of the problem.

All your suggestions are going to be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to adjust your MIME types in IIS.

Comment: How should I do it and where do I have to find it, I am on parallels plesk 11?